# iPhone and Blackberry integration with Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010, iphone, blackberry

I need to integrate a number of iPhones and Blackberries with an Exchange 2010 installation. Is this possible, or do they only connect via webmail, POP3 and IMAP? I can take no for an answer :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why you want to integrate them in the Exchange 2010. If the owner of the iphone or blackberry have account on the exchange server, they can retrieve the mail directly by configuring the phone.

Comment: The owners are VIPs in the organization and want to have access to calendars too.

Comment: well indeed, you need to integrate them.

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems with iOS 4.0 and Exchange 2010, but if they are running an updated patched version of iOS, iPhone users will be fine. iPhone 3G users don't support some important EAS policies. Our decision was to enforce strict security for newer devices, but add exceptions for iPhone 3G users.

If Webdav is enabled on your Outlook Web App server, Blackberry devices can connect to OWA and download messages through that. This is a bad security situation though. You should download at least the free version of Blackberry Enterprise Server, which is called Blackberry Enterprise Server Express (BESX). It's a pretty painless install, but make sure to configure and test it before your free support incident expires :) There were a few gotchas that we ran into with Exchange 2010 SP1. We had to manually configure the throttling policy and tweak several other settings.

BESX is a good product. It can be installed on the same server as Exchange, and it allows users to purchase the BIS Internet plan, which is $5 a month cheaper than the plan required to use a BES server.

Answer (score 2):

All iPhones should have the ability to connect to Exchange via the Microsoft Exchange account setup type on the iPhone. BlackBerry's would require a BES server if you want true integration.

They're both capable of connecting via POP or IMAP if that's the only options available to you.

Answer (score 1):

I know for certain that iPhones work with Exchange 2010, you can see a reference document provided by Apple [here](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iPhone_EAS.pdf).

For Blackberry handsets I believe you would need to install Blackberry Enterprise Server (BES) which I also believe supports Exchange 2010.